# How to sync between 2 file descriptors to the same file, one for reading one for writing

Tags: files, c

I have the following code:

```
FILE *file = fopen("testfile.txt", "r+");
int fdfile = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY | O_SYNC);

const char word[] = "writing to a file and read test";
fwrite(word, sizeof(word)-1, 1, file);

fsync(fdfile);

char word1[1024] = {0};
int n = read(fdfile, word1, sizeof(word)-1);

printf("%s\n%d", word1, n);

fclose(file);
```

Just before running this, the file `testfile.txt` has the content `prev content` in it

Once I run this, I get

```
prev content
12
```

even though it should be the latest contents, `writing to a file and read test`. I have used `fsync(fdfile)`, that doesn't work. I have also tried `sync()` and `fsync(fileno(file))`, none of which work, even though they should because they are supposed to flush the contents to disk after the write

I know the situation can be mitigated by using the same file descriptor to read and write both, but I am not in a position to do that in my code. How can I mitigate this issue and sync the contents?

Answer (score 3):

The `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, etc. functions are low level functions defined by Posix. They usually involve a buffer at the system level (kernel) and this is the buffer you are flushing to the actual medium with `fsync()` and you don't have much control over that buffer.

The `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()`, etc. functions are higher level functions offered by the C language. They involve and **additional** buffer which you can configure with `setbuf()`. This buffer is typically a line-buffer (flushed at each end of line `\n`) for text files (thus including `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`), and a block-buffer (flushed when the buffer is full) for binary files.

Of course this is discouraged to mix calls to both low-level and high-level read/write functions. Your issue is due to the fact that the high-level buffer used by `fwrite()` is not flushed (to the low-level buffer, which you flush with `fsync()`).

The solution is not to call `fsync()` or open with `O_SYNC` (you can remove those from your code); it is either:

- to explicitly flush the high-level buffer with `fflush()` when you need to
- or to make the high-level functions unbuffered with `setbuf(fdfile, _IONBF)`

The latter is easier but buffers are here to improve efficiency and unbuffering the high-level calls will cause each `fwrite()` to trigger a corresponding `write()` system call which may have an impact on performances, that's why you might prefer to `fflush()` when you deem it necessary.

Comment: fseek will also flush the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

The `FILE*` had its own buffer which needs to be `fflush()`ed before the `sync` can happen

Comment: Yes, exactly, see my answer. This is a misunderstanding that catches every C developer at least once, this is why your question is interesting and I took the time to answer.